# How to check from a command line that network is reachable?

Tags: command-line, networking, opensuse

I want to send a growl to myself after SuSE server finishes the boot process. I got this message `socket_sendto(): unable to write to socket [101]: Network is unreachable in`.

How can I check from command line if the network is reachable and wait in case it is not?

---

Comment: Linux one-liner to answer yes or no, are we connected to the internet: `ping -c 1 www.yourtrustedserver.com | grep " 0% packet loss"`.  What this does is ping the server with one packet, and greps the output for the string " 0% packet loss". (the space before the 0% is important) If the command returns a row, you are connected, otherwise, not connected.

Comment: This will fail if 1) yourtrustedserver.com's DNS is down 2) www.yourtrustedserver.com itself is down 3) your DNS recursor is down 4) your DNS recursor is misconfigured. The network might still be  reachable in all four of those cases, so it's not a good test.

Answer (score 20):

`ping` to an outside host can fail for a multitude of reasons, only a few of which actually say anything useful about the state of your own network.

As a first step, open a terminal window and type 
`ip route ls`

You should see an output along the lines of

```
shadur@equinox:~$ ip route ls
192.168.15.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.15.102 
default via 192.168.15.1 dev eth0
```

This indicates that your local network is an ethernet connection (`eth0`) with the address `192.168.15.0`, and that its default gateway through which it accesses the rest of the internet can be found at `192.168.15.1`.

Next, you can try to `ping` that address:

```
shadur@equinox:~$ ping 192.168.15.1
PING 192.168.15.1 (192.168.15.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.15.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=255 time=0.352 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.15.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=255 time=0.269 ms
^C
--- 192.168.15.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.269/0.310/0.352/0.045 ms
```

If you see something similiar to the above, your own local network is, at least, fine. At this point you can start looking with more advanced tools like `traceroute` to see where your connection to the destination might be failing.

However, after a quick google check of what `growl` is actually supposed to be I get the feeling that there's something else going wrong. Can you expand your question to give us a few more details on what you're trying to do, how you're attempting it, and the full error output? The line you're currently giving us gets cut off abruptly...

Comment: `ip route get 1.2.3.4` is more reliable than just doing `ip route ls`. The former will take into effect any rules that are in place in addition to routes. It also removes the possibility of misreading the routing table(s).

Answer (score 6):

A very simple and quick way is to use the `ping` command.

You can simply type

```
 $ ping yahoo.com
```

(or cnn.com or any other host) and see if you get any output back. This assumes that hostnames can be resolved (ie dns is working). If not, you can hopefully supply a valid IP address/number of a remote system and see if it can be reached.

Here's the [ping man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ping).

***Update***:

As a quick example, you can check the *return value* (e.g., with `"echo $?"`) from `ping` to see if the command succeeded (you could always pipe the output of the command to `> /dev/nul`). Note I use `-c 1` here, but you could use more.

```
$ ping -c 1 yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (72.30.38.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ir1.fp.vip.sp2.yahoo.com (72.30.38.140): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=83.5 ms

--- yahoo.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 83.593/83.593/83.593/0.000 ms

echo $?
0


$ ping -c 1 unicorns.are.here
ping: unknown host unicorns.are.here

$ echo $?
2
```

Comment: But how can I realize from using ping that everything is ok?

Comment: @Radek Have you tried running it yet?  ping tells you if it gets replies.

Comment: What if the server is on intranet only and doesn't have access to outside world?

Comment: @jw013: I haven't tried...I don't know to use ping from an unattended script.

Comment: @Radek it's quite simple.  I assume by 'connectivity' you mean it can talk to some other host on the intranet.  So run `ping -c 2 -n <other host's IP>` and operate on the return code: if true (0), then it has connectivity; if false (1), then it can't talk to that machine.

Comment: @Radek, @lxop has it right, you check the return value of the  count limited `ping` command. Note that I suggested the use of `ping` as a quick and simple check, even the other answer posted so far uses it.

Comment: @Radek I updated my answer by adding an example.

Comment: Thank you Levon. I used @lxop 's hint and almost have it done. Will finish it tomorrow and post my findings.

Answer (score 5):

I'd use `netcat` to the desired service.

For example, testing an IP port, succeding

```
> nc -zv 192.168.1.1 80
Connection to 172.26.0.1 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

...and failing

```
> nc -zv 192.168.1.1 22
netcat: connect to 172.26.0.1 port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

with 10s timeout

```
> nc -zv -w 10 10.0.0.1 80
netcat: connect to 10.0.0.1 port 80 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress
```

Comment: Hi Muihlinn, welcome to U&L! Could you give an example of how you would do this?

Answer (score 2):

[mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/) is a tool that is similar to ping but gives you more information such as packet lose, statistics on packet travel times, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function ... It defaults to quad9 but you can pass a different domain.  It will timeout after 15 minutes of trying

```
wait_for_dns() {

   local fqhn="quad9.net"
   fqhn=${1:-$fqhn}

   printf "waiting"
   for i in {1..15}; do
      local a_record=$(dig +short +time=2 $fqhn)

      if [[ $a_record != '' ]]; then
         printf "\n"
         return 0
      fi

      printf '.'
      sleep 60
   done

   printf "\n"
   return 1
}
```